# How to get the first row data of each list?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe

my DataFrame like this :

```
+------------------------+----------------------------------------+
|ID                      |probability                             |
+------------------------+----------------------------------------+
|583190715ccb64f503a|[0.49128147201958017,0.5087185279804199]|
|58326da75fc764ad200|[0.42143416087939345,0.5785658391206066]|
|583270ff17c76455610|[0.3949217100212508,0.6050782899787492] |
|583287c97ec7641b2d4|[0.4965059792664432,0.5034940207335569] |
|5832d7e279c764f52e4|[0.49128147201958017,0.5087185279804199]|
|5832e5023ec76406760|[0.4775830044196701,0.52241699558033]   |
|5832f88859cb64960ea|[0.4360509428173421,0.563949057182658]  |
|58332e6238c7643e6a7|[0.48730029128352853,0.5126997087164714]|
```

and I get the column of probability using

```
val proVal = Data.select("probability").rdd.map(r => r(0)).collect()
proVal.foreach(println)
```

the result is :

```
[0.49128147201958017,0.5087185279804199]
[0.42143416087939345,0.5785658391206066]
[0.3949217100212508,0.6050782899787492]
[0.4965059792664432,0.5034940207335569]
[0.49128147201958017,0.5087185279804199]
[0.4775830044196701,0.52241699558033]
[0.4360509428173421,0.563949057182658]
[0.48730029128352853,0.5126997087164714]
```

but I want to get the first column of data for each row, like this:

```
0.49128147201958017
0.42143416087939345
0.3949217100212508
0.4965059792664432
0.49128147201958017
0.4775830044196701
0.4360509428173421
0.48730029128352853
```

how can this be done?

The input is standard random forest input, above the input is `val Data = predictions.select("docID", "probability")`

```
predictions.printSchema()
```

> root
>    |-- docID: string (nullable = true)
>    |-- label: double (nullable = false)
>    |-- features: vector (nullable = true)
>    |-- indexedLabel: double (nullable = true)
>    |-- rawPrediction: vector (nullable = true)
>    |-- probability: vector (nullable = true)
>    |-- prediction: double (nullable = true)
>    |-- predictedLabel: string (nullable = true)

and I want to get the first value of the "probability" column

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `Column.apply` method to get the n-th item on an array column - in this case the first column (using index `0`):

```
import sqlContext.implicits._
val proVal = Data.select($"probability"(0)).rdd.map(r => r(0)).collect()
```

BTW, if you're using Spark 1.6 or higher, you can also use the Dataset API for a cleaner way to convert the dataframe into Doubles:

```
val proVal = Data.select($"probability"(0)).as[Double].collect()
```

Comment: Thanks, I use the method, but both methods throw the same error:  Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Can't extract value from probability#177; but the line 177 has the same structure as the other lines

Comment: If you can provide a sample input for which this fails - I'll be able to try to help, otherwise I can't see any obvious reason for this. Also - can you edit the question and add the result of `Data.printSchema()`?

Comment: the input is the standard random forest input, final result is the first value of the "probability" column,  `Data.printSchema()` result is : root
 |-- docID: string (nullable = true)
 |-- label: double (nullable = false)
 |-- features: vector (nullable = true)
 |-- indexedLabel: double (nullable = true)
 |-- rawPrediction: vector (nullable = true)
 |-- probability: vector (nullable = true)
 |-- prediction: double (nullable = true)
 |-- predictedLabel: string (nullable = true)